# How to turn a variable into a module with sys.modules hack?

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

```
import os
from glob import glob
from importlib import import_module

from django.urls import re_path as _re_path, path as _path


def _glob_init(name):
    name = name.replace('.', os.sep)
    path = os.sep + '**'
    modules = []
    for module in glob(name + path, recursive=True):
        importable = os.path.splitext(module)[0].replace(os.sep, '.')
        if '__' in importable:
            continue
        try:
            module = import_module(importable)
        except ModuleNotFoundError:
            module = import_module(importable[:-1])
        modules.append(module)
    return modules


class UrlManager:
    def __init__(self, views_root):
        self.views_root = views_root
        self._url_patterns = []

    def _path(self, route, kwargs=None, name=None, is_re=None):
        func = _re_path if is_re else _path

        def decorator(view):
            _view = view  # keep the original view
            if isinstance(view, type):
                view = view.as_view()
            self._url_patterns.append(
                func(route, view, kwargs=kwargs, name=name or view.__name__)
            )
            return _view

        return decorator

    def path(self, route, kwargs=None, name=None):
        return self._path(route, kwargs=kwargs, name=name, is_re=False)

    def re_path(self, route, kwargs=None, name=None):
        return self._path(route, kwargs=kwargs, name=name, is_re=True)

    @property
    def url_patterns(self):
        if isinstance(self.views_root, str):
            _glob_init(self.views_root)
        else:
            for root in self.views_root:
                _glob_init(root)
        return self._url_patterns
```

Basic usage:

```
# app.urls.py 

app_urls = UrlManager('app.views')
```

---

```
# app.views.py

from models import SomeModel
from urls import app_urls

@app_urls.path('foo/', name='foo')
def view(request):
    return response
```

---

```
# project.urls.py

from django.urls import include
from app.urls import app_urls

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(app_urls.urlpatterns))
]
```

Okay, now:

Everything works when you already have the migrations up and running, but when you want to create a new migration; due the fact that this code flow is something like:

--project urls.py imports app.urls

--app.urls imports views

--views imports models

--models doesn't exist yet because this is a migration command run

--error

I need to somehow either create a module named the instance so I can use `include('module.urls')` or some other way to postpone the imports.

Repo is at https://github.com/isik-kaplan/django_urls if anyone wants to open a pr.

Comment: If you have a problem when importing models when running migrations, then the problem is with your models, not with anything you have shown here. It is of course perfectly normal to import models when running migrations. But we cannot help because *you have not shown either the error or the models code*.

Comment: Hmm, maybe there is a db hit that I failed to see, I'll try to find anything that may hit the db, maybe I just missed it.